# Microsoft Excel - merging cells with date and time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRE3S.jpg]

I have Columns K and L, each with date and time. I want to merge the cells in the row of the two columns into one. By manually merging takes up a lot of time. And if I use formula such as concatenate, it gives me a series of number code which I can't reformat back to the date format.

Is there a way I can merge the cells without changing its format?

Comment: In your example I see blank cells, but none with the time?  Is that an oversight?

Comment: Are K and L mutually exclusive, so you can never have a case where both K and L have a date/time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to:

1. Select the entire column K
2. Click Home > Find & Select > Go To Special...
3. Choose "Blanks" and click OK. This will select only the blank cells in column A (which have no date)
4. Right click on selected cells and choose "Delete..."
5. Choose "Shift cells left" and click OK

This will shift data from column L into blank spaces in column K so you will have all dates in column K.

Edit: just to address your problem with using concatenate and getting a number: you probably need to use the `TEXT()` formula to set the formatting of the result.

```
        K    |    L    |     M
-----------------------------------
1  Mar-17    |         | =K1 & L1
   (1.3.17.) |         | >42795
-----------------------------------
2  Mar-17    |         | =TEXT(K2 & L2, "mmm-yy")
   (1.3.17.) |         | >Mar-17
```

Edit 2: Just to add a note: if you don't have English version of Excel or your Windows "Region and Language" settings are not English, the `TEXT` formula will give you results in your local language, even if you format the cells as "Date" and set the formatting Locale to English. To solve this, you can use the [language code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361638(v=office.14).aspx) in formula: `=TEXT(K2 & L2, "[$-409]mmm-yy")`

Comment: @fixer1234 hmm, I get a blank cell as a result if both columns are blank (Excel 2013)? What do you get?

Comment: Interesting.  You're right.  The TEXT function does treat that as a blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to only show the timestamp from one column or the other based on if one is blank or not, you can use an IF function to check for ISBLANK on one column and display it if it exists, or another column if it does not and place it in a new column.

Column C formula: `=IF(ISBLANK([@date1]),[@date2],[@date1])`

[image]

Comment: The example includes a case where both columns can be blank, like the last line in your example.  You might want to make the composite column blank in that case rather than show a nonsense date.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the columns are formatted.
@Rajesh S  Suggestion works fine for the text.

However, if the columns are formatted in the date and time format excel treats these as numeric values.

In which case

```
=K1+L1
```

Works just fine.  As they are both really just numbers.

If double nulls are a danger

```
=IF(AND(K1="",L1=""),"",K1+L1)
```

Comment: @fixer1234 I added a conditional IF.  However, it is impossible to continue with both being null as no value exists.

Comment: I had already upvoted this; it was what I was going to post and you beat me to it.  :-)